# Order Factorization in finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $g$ be an element of a finite group $G$ such that $o(g)$; the order of $g$ ; is of the form $o(g)=abc$ where 
$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Is it possible to find three elements $x,y,z$ in $G$ such that $g=xyz$ with $o(x)=a$,   $o(y)=b$ and  $o(z)=c$ ?

Clearly this is possible when one of $a,b$ or $c$ equal to 1. But I have no idea in the case when $a, b$ and $c$ are all different to 1.

Comment: If you can do it when there are just two coprime factors as you say, why not proceed in two steps, $abc=(ab)c$?

Comment: Thanks your are right .

Comment: You'd better post a solution! It's one of those problems which is easier to solve for the general case of $n$ mutually coprime factors, because the only possibility is an induction: with three one just tries to do it all at once.

Comment: It was my principal objective by I prefered to confirm the result for three elements and the same method; as you confirmed;  holds for $n$ coprime factors.  Thanks again!

Comment: It is, after all, just the Chinese Remainder Theorem plus $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce this to $g$ being an element with $o(g)=ab$, $gcd(a,b)=1$. Note that in general, $o(x^k)=\frac{o(x)}{gcd((k,o(x))}$ for any element $x$ of a group. Now, Bézout's theorem tells us that there exist integers, $k$ and $l$ such that $1=ka+lb \text{ } (*)$. Hence $g=g^{ka+lb}=g^{ka} \cdot g^{lb}$. Observe that $o(g^{ka})=\frac{ab}{gcd(ka,ab)}=\frac{b}{gcd(k,b)}$, and from $(*)$ it is obvious that $gcd(k,b)=1$. So $o(g^{ka})=b$. Likewise, $o(g^{lb})=a$ and we are done. Now you can extend the process to three factors since your condition $gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,c)=gcd(c,a)=1$ implies $gcd(ab,c)=1$.